# Swift 4 + Alamofire Decodable Json URL format

Tags: swift, alamofire, swift4, decodable

I have a JSON format which I do not decodable with Alamofire.

Here is my json:

```
"data":[  
{  
    "id":37,
    "status":"A\u00e7\u0131k",
    "department":"Muhasebe",
    "title":"Y\u00f6netim Panelinden Deneme 4 - Mail Kontrol",
    "message":"<p>Y\u00f6netim Panelinden Deneme 4 - Mail Kontrol<br><\/p>",
    "file":null,
    "created_at":{  
        "date":"2018-01-13 01:59:49.000000",
        "timezone_type":3,
        "timezone":"UTC"
    },
    "replies":[  
        {  
            "id":6,
            "ticket_id":37,
            "admin_id":null,
            "user_id":8593,
            "message":"<p>test<\/p>",
            "file":"uploads\/tickets\/8593-P87wd8\/GFV6H5M94y5Pt27YAxZxHNRcVyFjD554i80og3xk.png",
            "created_at":"2018-01-18 11:16:55",
            "updated_at":"2018-01-18 11:16:55"
        }
    ]
},
```

Here is my model for the JSON:

```
struct TeknikDestek : Decodable {
    var id: Int?
    var status: String?
    var title: String?
    var department: String?
    var message: String?

    var replies: [Replies]?
}

struct Replies: Decodable {
    var replyid: Int?
    var ticket_id: Int?
    var admin_id: Int?
    var user_id: Int?
    var message: String?
}
```

I called it Alamofire, but it does not come back when I do response.data.

```
        Alamofire.request("https://myurl.com.tr/api/tickets/\(userid)").responseJSON { (response) in

        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if((response.result) != nil) {
                let jsonData = response.data
                print("jsonData: \(test)")
                do{
                self.allReplies = try JSONDecoder().decode([TeknikDestek].self, from: jsonData!)
                    print(self.allReplies)

                    for reply in self.allReplies {
                        print("Reply: \(reply)")
                    }
                }catch {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
                self.view.dismissNavBarActivity()
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

This is the error console:
[image: Error console]

How can I make it work? I've spent several hours now but without success. Please help me. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is not related to `Alamofire`. It's only related to `JSONDecoder / Decodable`

You need an umbrella struct for the root object, which is a dictionary containing the `data` key, not an array. That's what the error message states.

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let data : [TeknikDestek]
}
```

Then decode `Root`

```
let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: jsonData!)
```

and get the replies with

```
self.allReplies = root.data.first?.replies // returns `nil` if data is empty
```

Note: It's highly recommended to name data structs in singular form (e.g. `Reply`), semantically you have a *collection of singular items*

Comment: Many Thanks. This code worked. How can I spend all the replies instead of the first one as well as eg. Just message?

Comment: There is a misunderstanding. `first` gets the first item of the outer array (for key `data`) which is not the same object as the *replies* array.